# How to link between two controllers and two views in HTML/erb

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

I am trying to make simple webboard application. In my question/show view, I have get method to link for action to answer_controller. But it seems not link to the answer view. The error is Sinatra does not know this path. I want to create the path from question/show.erb view to answer/new.erb via submit answer button. What should I do?

question_controller (Controller folder)

```
get '/questions/:id/show' do
@question = Question.find_by(id: params[:id])
erb :'question/show'
end
```

question/show (View folder)

```
<form method="get" controller="answers" action="/answers/question/<%=@question.id%>/new"> 
<input type=submit value="Answer"></form>
```

answer_controller (Controller folder)

```
get 'answers/question/:q_id/new' do
erb :'answer/new'
end
```

Comment: How is the rails tag relevant to this sinatra question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need the leading slash in the url of your answer route:

```
get '/answers/question/:q_id/new' do
  # ...
```